# Character translation chinese or japanese

Tags: translation, characters, traditional-characters

Can someone please help me figure out what characters are and how to translate the top four and the seal characters in the attached pic?
If you could please answer in a clear way to identify which is the top four characters and which are in the seal square[image][image]

Comment: Those aren’t real Chinese or Japanese characters. They got one character 用, but that’s probably a coincidence.

Comment: This is just an non-Chinese writer imitation of the pottery stamping, such stamping is called `底部押花款`.

Comment: Thanks. Crazy to think someone went to such a great length in creating this elaborate vase but butchered some simple characters

Answer (score 1):

my guess:

the top one is 呈 (u+5448)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=呈](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%91%88)

the second one is 瑞 (u+745e)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=瑞](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%91%9E)

others, it takes time to recognise :)

Comment: Thank you this is great. Really having a hard time even identifying the radicals of the other 2 characters

Comment: Could it be that the fourth is dragon 龙 ?

Comment: Also the third character second radical looks like Shou (hand) 手 in a caligraphic variation

Comment: the third one, it looks like 射 (u+5c04), or 財 (u+8ca1); unfortunately, i can't think any semantic "word", that coulee be matched. :(

Comment: Thanks. Bottom mark seems to say Jià Yong ( 嫁用 ) what do you think?

Comment: inventive :) traditionally, a seal should be read from top to bottom, right to left. so, i would think it's 用 + an / two unrecognisable character. then, again, use "x" as component, in the bottom left, or left; i can't think of any characters. as @droooze said, well, these characters derived seriously too far away from traditional chinese character. last, may i ask, what's the shape of this vessel / container? any other hints?

Comment: Just added a pic of the vase